# How to match set of strings that appear in radom order with regular expression

Tags: regex

There is a set of strings:

```
"foo","bar","baz", "boo", "123"
```

Which appear in text in random order, but numbers appear first:

```
Some text
     123 baz bar foo
     123 bar baz foo
     123 foo baz bar
Some other text
```

how can I match the line where they appear using regular expression?

Comment: Should the line match if it contains word/number not from the set? If the word from the set founds twice or more, should the line match?

Comment: it should match the line with text in the set and text won't appear more than once

Comment: It may be hard (even if possible) to find out the lines where there are no duplicates among the set words. But there is a way to workaround. You could shield those lines where are duplicates (with one regex) and then just scan the rest array of lines for your set match (another regex). And then delete the shield if needed.

Comment: thank you, will try that

Comment: To my previous comment: I meant it seems complicated to use one-regex technique to perform the matching.

Answer (score 1):

To perform the task you may try the shielding method:

1. Shield the lines containing duplicates as such lines should be excluded. You may then delete them if needed.
2. Match all the lines containing the words from the set.

So, an example text:

```
Some text
     123 baz bar foo
     123 bar baz foo
     123 foo baz bar
     123 foo baz bar foo boo
     123 foo bar bar
     123 boo baz foo asdf
Some other text
```

At first we should search the duplicate containing lines using the following regex:

```
(^.*(foo|bar|baz|boo|123).*\2)
```

The previous means: take a text from the beginning of line containing at least one duplicate word among the set ending with the matched duplicate.

Then shield these lines with the replacement using regex:

```
#SHIELD#\1
```

We will get the following text:

```
Some text
     123 baz bar foo
     123 bar baz foo
     123 foo baz bar
#SHIELD#     123 foo baz bar foo boo
#SHIELD#     123 foo bar bar
     123 boo baz foo asdf
Some other text
```

Or delete these lines if needed.

Then we will be able to get needed lines from the rest. Let us mark them with the replacement:

Find: `^(?!#SHIELD#)(\s*123.*(baz|bar|foo|boo).*)$`

(search only not shielded lines beginning with spaces, 123 and then any text with at least one match from the set).

Replace by: `#MYLINE#\1`

We get the text:

```
Some text
#MYLINE#     123 baz bar foo
#MYLINE#     123 bar baz foo
#MYLINE#     123 foo baz bar
#SHIELD#     123 foo baz bar foo boo
#SHIELD#     123 foo bar bar
#MYLINE#     123 boo baz foo asdf
Some other text
```